# PyQT button clicked name

Tags: qt, button, triggers, pyqt

I have dynamically created buttons`(QtoolButton)` in `gridLayout` in pyQT.
How can I get the name of the button clicked in the layout?

I can't know the name before hand.
Is there is any trigger to accomplish the task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can call `self.sender()` in a function connected to your button event to get the object that triggered the event. From there you can call the object's `objectName()` method to get the name.

Here's a quick example - the widget has 10 buttons and clicking on a button will update the label's text to show the button name.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QToolButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for button_number in xrange(1, 11):
            button = QToolButton()
            button.setText(str(button_number))
            button.setObjectName('Button%d' % button_number)
            button.released.connect(self.button_released)
            self.button_layout.addWidget(button)

        self.status_label = QLabel('No button clicked')

        self.widget_layout.addItem(self.button_layout)
        self.widget_layout.addWidget(self.status_label)
        self.setLayout(self.widget_layout)

    def button_released(self):
        sending_button = self.sender()
        self.status_label.setText('%s Clicked!' % str(sending_button.objectName()))




if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)

  widget = Widget()
  widget.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ Gary, but `.objectName()` is returning `None`. Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like you've not set an object name. If it's the button's text you want try `.text()` instead.

Comment: @ Gary, ya, i got the button text. How to find the `QAction` attached to which `QToolButton`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've not used QToolButtons before. Looking at the docs I'd guess `.defaultAction()`? It returns a `QAction` at least. http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtoolbutton.html

Comment: Just to add, to get the `QToolButton(QWidget)` from `QAction(QWidgetItem)` use `.getParent()` method for `QWidgetItem`

Comment: For those who get `unknown method sender()`, you have a unique object hierarchy, and you want to traverse your hierarchy to get to the parent widget/window

Comment: Any specific reason to use `widget_layout.addItem` instead of `addLayout`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to implement your iconlabel class derived from QToolButton:
Like This:

```
class IconLabel : public QToolButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit IconLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    bool event (QEvent* e );
    QString name;
signals:
    void clicked_signal(QString);

};



bool IconLabel::event (QEvent* e ) {
   if ( e->type() == QEvent::Paint) {
      return QToolButton::event(e);


   }
   if(e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
   {

       emit clicked_signal(name);
       return true;
   }

   return true;
}



connect(iconlabel, SIGNAL(clicked_signal(QString)), this, SLOT(getClickedButtonName(QString)));
```

Comment: I am using `lambda` like, `lambda: self.doSomthing(self.buttonName)`, its not working, how to use the callback??

Comment: May this be useful for you:    http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html

Comment: @ Rubby Thanks , for d link of doc.